# date is shown as fast milliseconds in java and not in proper format

Tags: java

I have the below declaration in java class

```
abc.setCreated(abcEntity.getCreatedDate());
```

and if I go deep inside the call inside abc entity

```
 public Date getCreatedDate() {

        return new Date(createdDate.getTime());
    }
```

but the date in the outcome of

```
abc.setCreated(abcEntity.getCreatedDate());
```

shown as in request `"created": 15704064000` and I want it to be shown as the date in DD-MM-YYYY format please advise how to achieve this

Comment: Did you mean `15,704,064,000` or `1,570,406,400` ?

Comment: Check this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` in java to get the date in that format. Instead of the time, pass the `Date` object like bellow.

ex:-

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String formattedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.
.ofEpochSecond(
    1_570_406_400L
)
.atOffset(
    ZoneOffset.UTC
)
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" )
)
```

> 07-10-2019

## Avoid legacy classes

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

## *java.time*

Parse your count of whole seconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC as a `Instant`.

Is your example value correct? Perhaps you meant 1,570,406,400.

```
long seconds = 1_570_406_400L ;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( seconds ) ;
```

The `Instant` represents a moment in UTC. Generate a string representing this value in standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2019-10-07T00:00:00Z

To adjust to another time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2019-10-06T20:00-04:00[America/Montreal]

Notice how the date is the 6th rather than the 7th. While at that moment a new day has begun in UTC, it is still “yesterday” in Canada. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone.

Generate a string a localized format.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" );
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

> output: 06-10-2019

If you want to report the date as seen in UTC rather than a time zone, use `OffsetDateTime` class. Specify UTC using the constant `ZoneOffset.UTC`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" );
String output = odt.format( f ) ;
```

> outputOdt: 07-10-2019

See all that code [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/DPvzJK).

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).